# Copy One custom field value to another custom field for a custom object

Tags: visualforce, trigger, javascript, formula

As in the accounts edit page, I want to achieve the Copy Billing address to shipping address for a custom object. I know this can be done either WF or trigger but I want that to be dynamic and based on user interaction. So I thought of using hyperlink. I have no idea of how to get that using hyperlink. Can anybody help me? or any other solution please?[image: Image1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the logic run in the browser you need to use JavaScript. We have a page that does this without using jQuery; there may be more elegant ways to accomplish the same thing but this works. Replace the Account field references with your custom object field references.

Here are the relevant parts

```
<apex:inputField id="b0" value="{!account.BillingStreet}"/>
<apex:inputField id="b1" value="{!account.BillingCity}"/>
<apex:inputField id="b2" value="{!account.BillingState}"/>
<apex:inputField id="b3" value="{!account.BillingPostalCode}"/>
<apex:inputField id="b4" value="{!account.BillingCountry}"/>

<apex:outputLink value="javascript: addressCopy('{!$Component.b0}', '{!$Component.b1}', '{!$Component.b2}', '{!$Component.b3}', '{!$Component.b4}', '{!$Component.s0}', '{!$Component.s1}', '{!$Component.s2}', '{!$Component.s3}', '{!$Component.s4}')">Copy Billing Address to Shipping Address</apex:outputLink>

<apex:inputField id="s0" value="{!account.ShippingStreet}"/>
<apex:inputField id="s1" value="{!account.ShippingCity}"/>
<apex:inputField id="s2" value="{!account.ShippingState}"/>
<apex:inputField id="s3" value="{!account.ShippingPostalCode}"/>
<apex:inputField id="s4" value="{!account.ShippingCountry}"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addressCopy(b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, s0, s1, s2, s3, s4) {
    // Copy billing fields to shipping fields
    document.getElementById(s0).value = document.getElementById(b0).value;
    document.getElementById(s1).value = document.getElementById(b1).value;
    document.getElementById(s2).value = document.getElementById(b2).value;
    document.getElementById(s3).value = document.getElementById(b3).value;
    document.getElementById(s4).value = document.getElementById(b4).value;
    // No form submission
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot :) Yes it worked. Cant we achieve this using hyperlink?

Comment: with the standard page layout of custom object, using hyperlink is this functionality possible? @Keith C

Comment: @ləːnə apex:outputLink does produce a HTML hyperlink. Using standard layouts you can add a JavaScript link but that doesn't appear in the edit view; also I don't know how you would get the right field ids. You should probably ask a separate question on this.